# Python infinite while loop pauses when it shouldn't until ctrl-c is pressed

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a python while-loop that posts oil futures data every minute to an API that is running on a Heroku server.
The while-loop is set to run infinitely. It runs completely fine for hours, until at some point, it just stops (this stopping point does not occur at a specific timeframe after the program is started). When I say stop, I don't mean the code is exited or an error is thrown. It just sits, not printing any output, until I hit CTRL-C, when it will continue its normal operation. The code is being run on an AWS server, and I did not run into the same issue running on my local machine.

See my code below:

```
def data_reader():

    while True:
        time_start = time.time()
        try:
            source = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5)

            source.encoding = 'utf-8' 
            status = source.status_code
            source = source.text
            soup =  BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
            divs = soup.find("div", {"id": "quotes_summary_current_data"})
            price = divs.find('span').text
            price = price.strip("'")
            price = float(price)
            now = (datetime.now()).strftime(timeformat)
            print(now)
            print(price)

            data_obj = {'time': now, 'close': price}


        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            now = (datetime.now()).strftime(timeformat)
            data_obj = {'time': now, 'close': 'NaN'}

        response = requests.post(base, data=data_obj)
        print(response.text)

     
        time.sleep(60)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_reader()
```

I also tried removing/changing the timeout parameter in requests.get(), to no avail.

My initial instinct is that some other process is being opened, and has to be killed until it can continue, but I have no idea why/where that would be happening.

Comment: Most likely either `requests.get` or `requests.post` is hanging waiting for a response from the server. Try putting print calls before and after each of them to see where it's getting stuck.

Comment: If left alone, will it revive itself? (e.g. `requests.post`/`requests.get` hanging for 5 minutes while waiting on a non-responsive server, then unhangs when the 5 minutes is up)  If not, it might be worthwhile doing a process listing before/after hitting ctrl+C and seeing if anything changed

Comment: Do you get a print from your exception clause when you ctrl-c? If so, try adding `import traceback;traceback.print_exc()` to find the guilty party.

Comment: can you put a `timeout` on your `requests.post`?

Comment: This isn't quite the real code (url and base are not defined). Is there some other place where the hang may be coming from?

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, sorry, I didn't want to publicly publish my API url, or the url I am pulling from. I can send it privately if need be. I'll definitely try a traceback, thank you!

Comment: @apnorton It doesn't revive itself, unfortunately. It'll just sit until I ctr+c the process. I'll try a process listing to see what happens. Thank you!

Comment: @Barmar Good thought. I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to find where the hang is happening. As Barmar notes, it's most likely in the IO operations but you need to find which one. If the halt is at the GET, it could be network layers intentionally halting automated GETs. If it's the POST, add debug to your Heroku process to see if the POST is received.

Comment: When the hang happens, are you able to manually curl GET or POST?

Comment: When the hang happens, what's your AWS OS logging?